# how to use PHP/Mysql generated json in AngularJS Application

Tags: php, mysql, json, apache, angularjs

**I generated some Json data from Mysql Database with PHP as below:**

**equipments.php**

```
<?php

    require("config.inc.php");

    //initial query
    $query = "Select * FROM equipment";

    //execute query
    try {
          $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
          $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
         }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
          $response["success"] = 0;
          $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
          die(json_encode($response));
         }

     // Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll 
     $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();


     if ($rows) {
         $response["success"] = 1;
         $response["message"] = "Equipment Available!";
         $response["equipments"]   = array();

     foreach ($rows as $row) {
         $post             = array();
    $post["EquipmentId"]  = $row["EquipmentId"];
         $post["Name"] = $row["Name"];
         $post["Ip"]    = $row["Ip"];
         $post["Brand"]  = $row["Brand"];
         $post["Location"]  = $row["Location"];

         //update our repsonse JSON data
         array_push($response["equipments"], $post);
        }


         // echoing JSON response
         echo json_encode($response);

       } else {
                $response["success"] = 0;
                $response["message"] = "No Equipment Available!";
                die(json_encode($response));
           }

       ?>
```

this returned the following data:

**//localhost/equip/equipments.php  (on my local apache server)**

```
{
 success: 1,
 message: "Equipment Available!",
 equipments: [
   {
    EquipmentId: "1",
    Name: "UCH-NET",
    Ip: "172.16.32.4",
    Brand: "Engenius",
    Location: "Top of ITD"
   },

   {
     EquipmentId: "2",
     Name: "UCH-PHOUSE",
     Ip: "172.16.32.5",
     Brand: "Mikrotik",
     Location: "Top of ITD"
   },

   {
     EquipmentId: "3",
     Name: "UCH-SON",
     Ip: "172.16.32.9",
     Brand: "MIkrotik",
     Location: "SON"
   },

  {
   EquipmentId: "4",
   Name: "UCH-GERIATRIC",
   Ip: "172.16.32.10",
   Brand: "Mikrotik",
   Location: "Geriatric"
  }
  ]
  }
```

**But when i try to use the returned Json like this in my AngularJS application no data is returned in the web page**

**services.js**

```
'use strict';

 var equipServices = angular.module('equipServices', ['ngResource']);

 equipServices.factory('Equip', ['$resource',
            function($resource){
            return $resource( '/equip/equipments.php/');

       }]);
```

**equipment.js**

```
    function EquipmentsCtrl ($scope, Equip) {
    $scope.setActive('equipments');

    $scope.sidebarURL = 'partials/equipment.html';
    $scope.currentEquipment = null;

        $scope.setEquipment = function (EquipmentId) {
        $scope.currentEquipment = $scope.equipments[EquipmentId];
    };

    $scope.equipments = Equip.query();

    }


}
```

**index.html**

```
    <title>IP Library</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/equipments.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/admins.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl" >
     <h1>IP Library</h1>
     <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li ng-class="equipmentsActive">
            <a href="#equipments" >Equipments</a>
         </li>
        <li ng-class="adminsActive">
           <a href="#/admins">Administrators</a>
       </li>
   </ul>

   <div ng-view></div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Is there something wrong with the way I am calling the php generated Json in my services.js?
Thanks**

Comment: or is there a better way to generate json from database in Linux OS for use in AngularJS application, in Windows OS i would have used ASP.NET web api.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Equip.get()` instead of `Equip.query()` because you are getting from server an object, not an array:

```
Equip.get(function(result){
    if(result.success === 1) // isn't better to return boolean?
        $scope.equipments = result.equipments;
    // else handle error
});
```

Comment: Thanks your suggestion fixed it. Would appreciate if you could give me hint on the best way to save new equipment back to mysql server from the angularjs app.